# Upload/retrieve files from a linux based file server using PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have 2 Linux boxes with same version installed. The first one is used to host a apache/linux based web site and the second one is used to host user supplied files.
The webserver box can access the file server box using an internal IP address. When user tries to upload a file using my php web site, I need to save this file in a specific folder in the file server box.

One option I found until now is to use PHP's FTP functions. Are there any other/better options to access folders/files that reside on a file server box from the web server box?

Thanks for any help!
- Jaideep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring an NFS server on the file server, and mounting the exported directory on your web server, will make programming easier for you, because you can access the directory just as if it was local.

In an environment where you don't have professional system administration, i'd recommend against the NFS version however, because NFS needs some planning regarding synchronized user ids, and it doesn't always recover gracefully from a crash (although it should, in theory). From that point of view, FTP might be your best option.